# How to use REST while using Java?

Tags: rest

I am using Spring MVC and want to develop a website that uses REST API provided by LinkedIn. I am very new to REST and have no Idea of how to use REST and retrieve data. I want a full tutorial so as to start up with my REST application. Please help me out through this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For consuming RESTful services the core class provided by spring is [`RestTemplate`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html)

The spring blog has a pretty good article on [how to use the RestTemplate](http://blog.springsource.com/2009/03/27/rest-in-spring-3-resttemplate/).

A very simplified example is:

```
class MyServiceClient {

    RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();

    public String get(String thingy){
        return rest.get("http://www.example.com/api/stuff/{thingy}", String.class, thingy);
    }
}
```

Comment: This indeed looks good. But what if I want to use it without any framework. What kind of felicities are provided by Java itself??

Comment: very very little..other than the low level API's of Socket and URL. new URL("http://").openConnection() will give you a GET request... with a bit more poking you can get PUT/POST etc but you have to manage all the marshalling of input and outputs your self.

Comment: Your question indicated that you are already using Spring MVC, assuming you are allowed to use spring 3 I would recommend using RestTemplate as it just kinda works and you can get on with writing your App

Comment: Yes I do. And thanks a lot for clarification :) Can you tell me whether Spring Social works well?? So that I can directly use it if I am building a social application?

Comment: I would say that Spring REST is probably much more cleaner than the traditional. Thanks

Comment: Can't help you with Spring Social I'm afraid. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

Try out rest4j. It integrates with Spring, but unlike Spring MVC, rest4j can generate documentation and client libraries for different programming languages.

There is also a flexible mechanism for mapping your internal Java object to external JSON representation, which is very important when using an ORM.